# finding number of words in a String using recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

I want to count number of words in my string using  recursive method (java)

so far i wrote this code

```
public static int CountWords(String sen) {
    int count = 0;
    int i = sen.indexOf(" ");
    if (sen.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }else 
        if (i == sen.indexOf(" ")) {
      return count++;
   }
  //sen.substring(0,sen.indexOf(" ")-1);
    count++;
    return count + CountWords(sen.substring(i + 1));
}
```

i always get 0 when i call the method
can anyone help me make this code run

Answer (score 3):

How you're using `indexOf` is the problem. You're setting `i` to the result of calling `indexOf`, then seeing if it's equal to the result of calling `indexOf` on the same string with the same parameter. The result of the test `i == sen.indexOf(" ")` will always be true. That's why you always get 0.

`String#indexOf` returns -1 if the char it's looking for is not found. `indexOf` comes in very handy here.

Also you shouldn't need a local count variable. Introducing a variable here just makes the code harder to read, because the reader has to hunt around to figure out what the value of it is.

Assuming your input always has exactly one blank between words this could be done as:

```
public static int countWords(String s) {
    if (s.isEmpty()) return 0;
    if (s.indexOf(" ") == -1) return 1;
    return 1 + countWords(s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1));
}
```

For multiple blanks between words you can check for a blank and skip past it:

```
public static int countWords(String s) {
    if (s.isEmpty()) return 0;
    if (s.indexOf(' ') == -1) return 1;
    if (s.charAt(0) == ' ') return countWords(s.substring(1));
    return 1 + countWords(s.substring(s.indexOf(' ') + 1));
}
```

Comment: If you send in the `String`, `"The cow jumped over the moon \\"` then you get 7 as the count. OP should consider improving the algorithm to detect this.

Comment: Also probably need a defensive check if the `String` is null.

Comment: @staticx: that is good advice, but i felt like i needed to leave something for the OP. It looked like the core problem was not getting recursion, so that was the scope of my answer.

Comment: No problem, your response is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually looking at the OP's code now, i think the problem was just not getting the termination condition right.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, I think:

```
public static int countWords(String sen) {
    int i = sen.indexOf(" ");
    if (sen.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    } else if (i == -1) {
        return 1;
    } else return 1 + countWords(sen.substring(i + 1));
}
```

Some notes on what is happening:

1. Java naming conventions dictate you should start method names with a lower case letter
2. The line `if (i == sen.indexOf(" "))` is redunant - you just assigned `i` to be that before, so it'll always evaluate to true.
3. And therefore, your recursion never gets called. You need to change it so that if `sen` isn't empty and contains at least one more space, `countWords` calls itself with `sen` minus the first word.

Comment: There's no point getting the `indexOf(" ")` if `sen` is empty. If you move that check down to `countWords` recursive call, then you essentially get @NathanHughes' answer.

Comment: Also probably need a defensive check if the `String` is null.

Comment: @staticx True. I had adapted the OP's code and that must have slipped by. On an empty string, the performance hit should be negligible, but you are right, it's not as pretty as it could be.

Comment: Not sure I agree on the defensive `null` check. I'm not a fan of defensively `null` checking excessively if there is no clearly appropriate value. I guess it depends on the definition of how many words a null string has: 0, or is it an error to ask.

Comment: If you call `isEmpty` on a null `String`, you get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I know. Actually, with my code, you already will with the call to `indexOf`. What I'm saying is it's a design decision of whether or not `null` should result in an exception or a default value. I will admit though that the NPE should probably be replaced with an `IllegalArgumentException` if you go down the exception route.

Comment: IMHO, if it is `null`, then return 0. But to avoid stepping on your own proverbial foot, you need to do a `sen != null || sen.isEmpty()`, before anything else. Ideally, the interface will define this but you can't control what other people send in. Plus, you already have the `isEmpty` so what's adding another `!= null` beforehand.

Comment: I can comfortably live with `countWords(null) == 0`. All I'm saying is, as a design decision, it's something the OP needs to decide. Actually, what I'd do instead of `sen != null || ...` is `if (sen == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot count words on a null string")` as the very first statement. But to avoid stepping on _your_ proverbial foot in return I will agree on the following  stipulations: 1. `null` is a border case that needs to be thought of here 2. 0 is a sensible return value for that ;)

Comment: And also to you! Agree to disagree ;)

Answer (score 0):

This method uses a String with no spaces as a base case. Then it removes everything up to and including the first space in the String and recurses.

It handles both the special case of an empty String and the case that a String passed to the method starts with a space appropriately.

```
public static int CountWords(String sen) 
{   int i = sen.indexOf(" ");
    if(sen.isEmpty()) return 0;          // special case
    if(i == -1) return 1; // base case

    if(i != 0)
        return 1 + CountWords(sen.substring(i+1));
    else
        return CountWords(sen.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to ask others to review your code.

Comment: Suggest you save `sen.indexOf(" ")` to a local variable since your code uses it up to three times.

Comment: Edited as suggested.

Answer (score -3):

This will work -

```
public static int CountWords(String sen) {
    if("".equals(sen)){
        return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    int i = sen.indexOf(" ");
    String substr = sen.substring(0,i+1) ;
    if (i != -1) {
        count++;
    }else{
        if(sen.length()>0){
            count++;
        }
        sen="";
    }
    //sen.substring(0,sen.indexOf(" ")-1);
    return count + CountWords(sen.substring(substr.length()));

}
```

Comment: While it may work, this is not a good way to code recursively. You've basically written it iteratively, then left out the loop, threw the iterative prep work out the window and called the recursion instead. See my code or @Nathan Hughes for how this is done elegantly with recursion.

Comment: I agree, but optimization was not the question. This code is just the fix of the code in the OP.

Comment: Whatever the question may have been, answers should strive to show a good solution to the problem, adhering to coding standards and best practices. Even if you "fix" the code in the OP, your answer provides little value to future readers.